# Text not changing after button click

Tags: java, android

I need some android programming help. So onbutton click i call in the icite method. Basically when the button is clicked, all of the text box texts are converted to a string onto a new variable. After that i combine all the variables to a string called Total. I then change the text of label textView10 to the string Total. However it just crashes my app. Do you know what i could be doing wrong?
My logcat:

```
11-17 03:02:43.652: W/dalvikvm(1952): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1f60648)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.example.randomapplication.citationsPage$1.onClick(citationsPage.java:59)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-17 03:02:43.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 03:02:45.552: D/dalvikvm(1982): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 92K, 11% free 2541K/2832K, paused 8ms, total 9ms
11-17 03:02:45.552: I/dalvikvm-heap(1982): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.277MB for 635808-byte allocation
11-17 03:02:45.562: D/dalvikvm(1982): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 3162K/3456K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
11-17 03:02:45.572: D/dalvikvm(1982): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 3162K/3456K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
11-17 03:02:45.572: I/dalvikvm-heap(1982): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.753MB for 500412-byte allocation
11-17 03:02:45.592: D/dalvikvm(1982): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 3650K/3948K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
11-17 03:02:45.662: D/libEGL(1982): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
11-17 03:02:45.662: D/(1982): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7acdfa0, tid 1982
11-17 03:02:45.672: D/libEGL(1982): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
11-17 03:02:45.682: D/libEGL(1982): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
11-17 03:02:45.692: W/EGL_emulation(1982): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-17 03:02:45.702: D/OpenGLRenderer(1982): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Code

```
package com.example.randomapplication;

import java.util.Calendar;


    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ClipData;
    import android.content.ClipboardManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class citationsPage extends Activity {
    EditText editText1;
    EditText author;
    EditText articleTitle;
    EditText webTitle;
    EditText editText2;
    EditText webDay;
    EditText webMonth;
    EditText webYears;
    TextView textView10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.citations);
        final Button citationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        citationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                // Gets date from the calendar!
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                String month1 = String.valueOf(month);
                String day1 = String.valueOf(day);
                String year1 = String.valueOf(year);

                editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.author);
                articleTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.articleTitle);
                webTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webTitle);
                webDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webDay);
                webMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webMonth);
                webYears = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webYears);


                String authorFirst1 = editText1.getText().toString();
                String authorLast1 = author.getText().toString();
                String articleTitle1 = articleTitle.getText().toString();
                String website1 = webTitle.getText().toString();
                String Publisher1 = editText2.getText().toString();
                String month2 = webMonth.getText().toString();
                String day2 = webDay.getText().toString();
                String year2 = webYears.getText().toString();
                TextView citationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                String Total = authorLast1+","+" "+authorFirst1+"."+" "+"\""+articleTitle1+"."+"\""+" "+website1+"."+" "+Publisher1+","+" "+day2+" "+month2+" "+year2+"."+" "+"Web"+"."+" "+day+" "+month+"."+" "+year+".";
                citationText.setText(authorFirst1);



            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") public void iCite() {


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Gets date from the calendar!
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        String month1 = String.valueOf(month);
        String day1 = String.valueOf(day);
        String year1 = String.valueOf(year);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.author);
        articleTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.articleTitle);
        webTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webTitle);
        webDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webDay);
        webMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webMonth);
        webYears = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webYears);


        String authorFirst1 = editText1.getText().toString();
        String authorLast1 = author.getText().toString();
        String articleTitle1 = articleTitle.getText().toString();
        String website1 = webTitle.getText().toString();
        String Publisher1 = editText2.getText().toString();
        String month2 = webMonth.getText().toString();
        String day2 = webDay.getText().toString();
        String year2 = webYears.getText().toString();
        TextView citationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        String Total = authorLast1+","+" "+authorFirst1+"."+" "+"\""+articleTitle1+"."+"\""+" "+website1+"."+" "+Publisher1+","+" "+day2+" "+month2+" "+year2+"."+" "+"Web"+"."+" "+day+" "+month+"."+" "+year+".";
        citationText.setText(Total);

        /*ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        Uri copyUri = Uri.parse(authorLast1+","+" "+authorFirst1+"."+" "+"\""+articleTitle1+"."+"\""+" "+website1+"."+" "+Publisher1+","+" "+day2+" "+month2+" "+year2+"."+" "+"Web"+"."+" "+day+" "+month+"."+" "+year+".");
        //ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(Total + "");
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(),"URI",copyUri);
        */


    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat error please.

Comment: are you defining `button10` in your `citation.xml` layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views causes `nullpointerexception` because they are part of `R.layout.citations` not button view. So Define below views to outside of onclick

```
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.author);
        articleTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.articleTitle);
        webTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webTitle);
        webDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webDay);
        webMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webMonth);
        webYears = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webYears);
        TextView citationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
```

and also you forget to initialize editText2,So init it also as

```
  editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

i.e. rewrite onCreate method as

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.citations);
    final Button citationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.author);
    articleTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.articleTitle);
    webTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webTitle);
    webDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webDay);
    webMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webMonth);
    webYears = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webYears);
    final  TextView citationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);


    citationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            // Gets date from the calendar!
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            String month1 = String.valueOf(month);
            String day1 = String.valueOf(day);
            String year1 = String.valueOf(year);

            String authorFirst1 = editText1.getText().toString();
            String authorLast1 = author.getText().toString();
            String articleTitle1 = articleTitle.getText().toString();
            String website1 = webTitle.getText().toString();
            String Publisher1 = editText2.getText().toString();
            String month2 = webMonth.getText().toString();
            String day2 = webDay.getText().toString();
            String year2 = webYears.getText().toString();
            String Total = authorLast1+","+" "+authorFirst1+"."+" "+"\""+articleTitle1+"."+"\""+" "+website1+"."+" "+Publisher1+","+" "+day2+" "+month2+" "+year2+"."+" "+"Web"+"."+" "+day+" "+month+"."+" "+year+".";
            citationText.setText(authorFirst1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @RifatRashid you forget to initialize editText2,So init it also as

  `editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);` see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Giru-Bhai, the component views have to be defined upon creating the view, in `OnCreate()` method, not inside any other method, so this block have to be only once:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.citations);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.author);
    articleTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.articleTitle);
    webTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webTitle);
    webDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webDay);
    webMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webMonth);
    webYears = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webYears);
```

now, on line

```
String Total = authorLast1+","+" "+authorFirst1+"."+" "+"\""+articleTitle1+"."+"\""+" "+website1+"."+" "+Publisher1+","+" "+day2+" "+month2+" "+year2+"."+" "+"Web"+"."+" "+day+" "+month+"."+" "+year+".";
        citationText.setText(authorFirst1);
```

I believe there's an error as you set the content of the label CitationText as authorFirst1, also the concatenation may be improved.

```
String Total = authorLast1+","+" "+authorFirst1+"."+" "+"\""+articleTitle1+"."+"\""+" "+website1+"."+" "+Publisher1+","+" "+day2+" "+month2+" "+year2+"."+" "+"Web"+"."+" "+day1+" "+month1+"."+" "+year1+".";
        citationText.setText(authorFirst1);

String Total = authorLast1+", "+authorFirst1+". \""+articleTitle1+".\" "+website1+"."+Publisher1+", "+day2+" "+month2+" "+year2+". "+"Web"+". "+day1+" "+month1+". "+year1+".";
        citationText.setText(Total);
```

If you aren't working with arrays, the only reason you get a NullPointerException is when you address to a view the code doesn't recognize. All views must be declared as part of the layout as soon as you start to write `OnCreate()` method.